# InputStream reads extra bytes which are not exist in source

Tags: java, sockets, stream, byte, inputstream

I have the Java server that receives the RTMP packets that are sent from client app. The server reads the `packet header` using `InputStream`, recognizes how big the `packet body` is, then creates `byte array` with that `size`, and then reads that `body` from `InputStream` in that `array`.
**The problem is:** the received set of bytes are **modified** - there are neccessary bytes (that exist in source) standing with extra bytes that don't exist in the source packet (I watch the content of the source packet via WireShark and compare them with those bytes that I received on the server).
These extra bytes are `0xc6` bytes that meet periodically by the way...
It looks like this:
`Source: ... 75 f1 f5 55 73 .... fc a9 47 14 ... 40 ca d5 75 ... fe 30 a7`
`Received: ... 75 f1 f5 55 73 c6 .... fc a9 47 14 c6 ... 40 ca d5 75 c6 ... fe 30 a7`
`...` - means *"some quantity of bytes here"*
As a result, I can't receive neccessary data because it's stretched, it's bigger than it have to be, than the `body size` that I received from rtmp `header`. And most importantly, that modified data is not what I had to receive!
**My questions are:** how can it be fixed? What's wrong with `InputStream`? Why does it insert those `0xc6` bytes to the receiving array?
I understand that I can simply parse received array and exclude those extra bytes, but this is bad solution, since speed and performance are neccessary (and, in this case, it's not clear that it's an extra byte or byte from source, without the comparison of whole arrays) ...

```
enter code here
public static void getRtmpPacket(InputStream in) throws Exception {

    byte[] rtmpHeader = new byte[8];
    byte[] rtmpBody;
    int bodySize = 0;

    //reading rtmp header:
    in.read(rtmpHeader);
    //reading the body size. This method works fine
    bodySize = Server.bigEndianBytesToInt(rtmpHeader, 4, 3);
    rtmpBody = new byte[bodySize];
    in.read(rtmpBody);
    //printing received data:
    System.out.println("Packet:");
    System.out.println("Body size: " + bodySize);
    System.out.print(bytesToString(rtmpHeader) + " ");
    System.out.print(bytesToString(rtmpBody));
    System.out.println();

}
```

Comment: Code, please. Preferably reduced into a [mcve].

Comment: `InputStream` never does that. If it does, it means the source is not as well bound as you think it is.

Comment: This is not credible. Obviously you have bugs int he cod you haven't posted, such as `bytesToString()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the RTMP spec, it behaves normally. You need to "unchunk" the incoming data, so reading it all at once in a single read() will not work.

Something along these lines (pseudocode):

```
int remaining = payloadSize;
int totalRead = 0;
int totalReadForChunk = 0;
while (true) {
  int num = read(buf, 0, min(remaining, chunkSize - totalReadForChunk))
  if (num < 0) break;  // i/o error
  appendData(<buf>, 0, num)
  totalReadForChunk += num
  remaining -= num
  if (remaining == 0) break;  // end of payload

  if (totalReadForChunk == chunkSize) {
     totalReadForChunk = 0;
     // read the chunk header (it's not neccessarily 0xc6)
     int header = read()
     if (header != currentStreamEmptyHeader) {  // 0xc6
       // ... parse the new rtmp message according to header value
       // (usually invoke the upper-level message reading method "recursively")
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your example. Please correct me, if I'm wrong: as I understood, you mean that I need to read all the packet chunk by chunk (for example, if chunk size is 128 bytes, read that 128 bytes, and then do it again unti the end of body size)? Sorry for stupid questions, I'm a newbie in this area...

Comment: Yes, try to read an entire chunk (or less than that if remaining expected data is smaller), and after each entire chunk, repeat the process from the higher layer (e.g. as if you start reading a new message, which might be on the same stream, or from another, according to the next byte you'll read, which is the next chunk header). This means you can end up with some other messages from other streams before finishing reading the payload of the current one.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. I'm almost done with it, but i still have some unclear parts of this process. Please, help me understand them.
Client sends first video packet to server (from flash player). From that packet's header I get the size of the body -> about 28000bytes. Previously I set up the chunk size to 4096 by command "Set Chunk Size 4096" (sent form server). However, when I'm trying to read that body, it is separated by chunks with **128** size (every chunk ends up with 0xc6 byte). And at this point i don't clearly understand what I sould do next (I'll explain it in the next comment)

Comment: My payload size will be that body size (specified in packet header). But I don't understand what do you mean in the comments of your example.
`if (header != currentStreamEmptyHeader) {  // 0xc6 // ... parse the new rtmp message according to header value` - when i read the first 128bytes-chunk of a packet(about 28000bytes) I'll met the 0xc6. According to the comment, in this case I need to invoke the upper-level message reading method, but those bytes after this 0xc6 don't contain the apropriate header format... They are just a remained part of those 28000bytes.

Comment: I can read the whole body size chunk by chunk, and then I'll gathered all together (header that was read previously, and body, that was read chunk by chunk). The question is: do I need to append the 0xc6 byte to the end of the every chunk (especially when I sending them to the other client/peer)

Comment: There's two chunk sizes: one used to read, one used to write. New chunk size has effect for all future messages after chunk size is received / sent  Please read the RTMP spec. 0xc6 is not a random value, it should be parsed as the header of a message (and as such translates to "no additional header bytes", which means that the StreamID, timestamp are to be kept, and message size is 0 => in effect keep reading and write to the same message payload). BUT it will sooner or later be the header of a new chunk of another stream (let's say the server decides to send a ping on the control stream).

Comment: 0xc6 is not something you *append*, it's a header that you *prepend* before every chunk data that you send (except the first of course). You should start (for the first chunk) with a complete chunk header, and after every N bytes of the payload, you use the shorter header of a single byte (3 << 6 | chunkStreamId). This is where the 0xc6 comes from: the flags of 3 indicate the header doesn't have any extra bytes for changed info, and the 6 (lowest 6 bits) was your current stream id.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Now the things are getting clearer)
May I speak with you via email or chat-like application? I still have some questions related with rtmp (especially chunk re-sending) but they are out of this topic, and you are the one who really helped me for last 2 month in this area...

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you should see (and use) code of Red5 Media Server and other open-source solutions that implement RTMP protocol.

Answer (score 0):

InputStream.read(byte[]) is only guarenteed to read one byte, and it return the length as an `int` of the actual length read.

```
in.read(rtmpHeader); // might read 1, 2, 3, .. 8 bytes.
//reading the body size. This method works fine
bodySize = Server.bigEndianBytesToInt(rtmpHeader, 4, 3);
rtmpBody = new byte[bodySize];
in.read(rtmpBody); // might read 1, 2, 3, ... bodySize bytes.
```

If you don't check the actual length, and assume the byte[] is full, you get whatever bytes where there before you called read().

What you intended is available using DataInputStream

```
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(in);

int len = dis.readInt(); // read an int in big endian.
byte[]] bytes = new byte[len];
dis.readFully(bytes); // read the whole byte[] or throw an IOException.
```

Comment: Everything you wrote is quite right, but it does not seem to explain the OP's key claim and concern: that in his single `read()` intended to input the whole message payload, he gets spurious bytes intermixed with the expected ones (not just at the end).

Comment: @JohnBollinger it's not clear whether the spurious bytes are in the header, in the body or at the end. It is possible the format isn't what the OP expects e.g. it could be a 9 byte header....

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved.
Those extra `0xc6` bytes were the chunking bytes of RTMP packet, which were not visible from the WireShark.
More than this, received header says the actual body size and WireShark "confirms" it, but in fact the body size will be bigger, and should be calculated.

- https://www.wireshark.org/lists/wireshark-bugs/200801/msg00011.html
- http://red5.osflash.narkive.com/LYumrzr4/rtmp-video-packets-and-streaming-thereof#post12

Comment: RTMP chunking is on the lower-level of the transport, so it should have priority when decomposing the actual RTMP message payload. Note that it resets with every new RTMP message. Don't forget to also add it back when replying back with data, it may happen that your payload will sometimes be bigger than the current chunk size, and you won't know why you end up with a closed connection (server not being capable of parsing your messages).

Comment: @AdrianCrețu could you give me some example of this process, please? I really need detailed info about chunking (correct receving this chunks at the server, and sending to other peer), because I have some problems with it, and official specification is not enough